# How to connect all the contours?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I need to connect the outer edges and form a rectangle so that it will be the largest contour from the source image:

[image]

I have tried dilation and morphological close, but it does not work for me. Any help will be appreciated!

Expected output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Heavy usage of [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) incoming:

- Count non-zero pixels along the x-axis. Get y indices of all rows with at least one non-zero pixel.

  - First index is `ymin` of top line.
  - Last index is `ymax` of bottom line.
- Calculate differences between y indices (using [`np.diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html)) to distinguish whole lines (instead of rows).

  - First index (mapped into y indices) is `ymax` of top line.
  - Last index (mapped into y indices + 1) is `ymin` of bottom line.
- Focus on top line part of image, get min and max of non-zero pixels, i.e. `xmin` and `xmax` of top line.
- Focus on bottom line part of image, get min and max of non-zero pixels, i.e. `xmin` and `xmax` of bottom line.

That'd be the code (using the Python API):

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage import io              # Only needed for web reading images

# Web read image; use cv2.imread(...) for local images
img = cv2.cvtColor(io.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8xJr.jpg'), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

# Threshold grayscale version of image to get rid of JPG artifacts
img_thr = cv2.threshold(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY), 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# Determine min/max y values for both lines
y_idx = np.where(np.count_nonzero(img_thr, axis=1))[0]
line1_ymin = y_idx[0]
line2_ymax = y_idx[-1]
thr_inter_line = 10
yy_idx = np.where(np.diff(y_idx) > thr_inter_line)[0]
line1_ymax = y_idx[yy_idx[0]]
line2_ymin = y_idx[yy_idx[-1]+1]

# Determine min/max x values for both lines
line1_xmin = np.min(np.where(img_thr[line1_ymin:line1_ymax, :] == 255)[1])
line1_xmax = np.max(np.where(img_thr[line1_ymin:line1_ymax, :] == 255)[1])
line2_xmin = np.min(np.where(img_thr[line2_ymin:line2_ymax, :] == 255)[1])
line2_xmax = np.max(np.where(img_thr[line2_ymin:line2_ymax, :] == 255)[1])

# Draw rectangles for both lines
img_thr = cv2.rectangle(img_thr, (line1_xmin, line1_ymin), (line1_xmax, line1_ymax), 255, cv2.FILLED)
img_thr = cv2.rectangle(img_thr, (line2_xmin, line2_ymin), (line2_xmax, line2_ymax), 255, cv2.FILLED)

cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.imshow('img_thr', img_thr)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

That'd be the output:

[image: Output]

Hope that helps!

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:    Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:      3.8.1
NumPy:       1.18.1
OpenCV:      4.2.0
----------------------------------------
```